# How can I use the raspberry pi to read analog voltages

Tags: analog-to-digital

I have a device that puts out 0-5v based on what it's doing. How can I use the raspberry pi to read those voltages? I would then have scripts do whatever is needed or maybe display via a webpage. I would like the pi to log the readings every second or every few seconds, just not sure how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter).

Google MCP3008 (a popular 10-bit 8 channel ADC) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ADC built into most* Arduino and connect to it using you RPi via a python script as depicted in this [tutorial](http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/raspberry-pi-measures-voltage-via-arduino/)

[image: image from http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/raspberry-pi-measures-voltage-via-arduino/]

Comment: This was a great answer too. The other one was just more direct. I think I will end up doing this, cause I have to build a few systems once I get them up and going quickly.